# Jest is not familiar with SubmitEvent, throws ReferenceError: SubmitEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, web-component, ts-jest

I'm trying to create a unit test in `StencilJS` app for a submit event but it seems jest does not know what `SubmitEvent` is. I'm getting an error of `ReferenceError: SubmitEvent is not defined`. Anyone knows how to bypass this error, or how is it possible to mock this event so the form can emit this and the app can catch this event and run the relevant code?

```
  it('runs handleSubmit function on submit', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [Input],
      template: () => (
        <form id="form">
          <button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
          <my-input validator={validatorFunc}></my-input>
        </form>
      ),
    });
    
    // page.rootInstance is the reference to the component class and handleSubmit is the handler to the listener of the submit event
    const handleSubmitSpy = jest.spyOn(page.rootInstance, 'handleSubmit');
    const submit = page.body.querySelector('#submit') as HTMLButtonElement;
    const form = page.body.querySelector('#form') as HTMLFormElement;

    const e = new SubmitEvent('submit', { submitter: submit }); // throws ReferenceError: SubmitEvent is not defined
    await form.dispatchEvent(e);
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(handleSubmitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The `submit` handler of the Stencil component:

```
  @Listen('submit', { target: 'document' })
  async handleSubmit() {
     ... do stuff related to submit event
  }
```